# Kyocera network printer suddenly not reachable on ubuntu

Tags: networking, printing

After a reset of our local network, the Kyocera FS-C5250DN printer does not work any more. I tried to remove and add it again: When trying to add, the system settings dialogue finds it in the network and allows installation of the printer. However, when trying to print, it tells that the printer cannot be reached.

- Printing via USB connection works (but network printing is necessary as multiple computers need to use it)
- Printing from a Windows machine over network, using the official kyocera driver works.
- I already installed the kyocera driver package: "KyoceraLinux-Phase5-2018.08.29". Does not make a difference (except for the correct driver being suggested by default).
- Another printer (HP) in the same network does work.

Nmap Scan on the printers IP shows:

```
PORT     STATE    SERVICE     VERSION
21/tcp   filtered ftp
80/tcp   filtered http
139/tcp  open     netbios-ssn Konica Minolta bizhub C452 printer smbd
161/tcp  filtered snmp
443/tcp  filtered https
445/tcp  open     routersetup Nortel/D-Link router instant setup
515/tcp  filtered printer
631/tcp  filtered ipp
9090/tcp open     soap        gSOAP 2.7
9100/tcp filtered jetdirect
9101/tcp filtered jetdirect
9102/tcp filtered jetdirect
9103/tcp filtered jetdirect
```

What puzzles me most ist that it works on Windows. Are there different protocolls/ports being used?

Any ideas?

Comment: All the ports for printing are shown as *filtered*. This means that nmap cannot tell whether a port is open or closed. This sometimes indicates a firewall is blocking a port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not being able to solve the problem, I bought a print server that connects to the printer via USB and makes it available over the network. Even though it's not a beautiful solution it works.